# Different key_len results in same database (different enviroments)

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, indexing, explain

I have a production database in AWS, but same database in localhost is much more faster(25s VS 7s), doing some research I've found one discrepancy in same SQL:

```
EXPLAIN extended 
SELECT * 
FROM pipeline p 
JOIN invoice i ON p.invoice_id = i.id 
WHERE i.whenCreated BETWEEN "2017-01-01 00:00:00" AND "2017-01-31 00:00:00"
```

In AWS =====> key_len = 8 and Extra = Using where.
In localhost ==> key_len = 5 and Extra = Using index condition.

I ran in both sites before:

```
OPTIMIZE TABLE invoice;
```

Probably it is a config problem, but I'm lost.

---

More info:
Mysql version in AWS: **5.5.46**
Mysql version in Localhost: **5.6.24**

explain in AWS:

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: i
         type: range
possible_keys: PRIMARY,IDX_5FD82ED84DD79520
          key: IDX_5FD82ED84DD79520
      key_len: 8
          ref: NULL
         rows: 847
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: Using where
*************************** 2. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: p
         type: ref
possible_keys: UNIQ_848ABB8F2989F1FD
          key: UNIQ_848ABB8F2989F1FD
      key_len: 5
          ref: ontrocrm.i.id
         rows: 1
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: Using where
```

explain in localhost:

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: i
         type: range
possible_keys: PRIMARY,IDX_5FD82ED84DD79520
          key: IDX_5FD82ED84DD79520
      key_len: 5
          ref: NULL
         rows: 847
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: Using index condition
*************************** 2. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: p
         type: ref
possible_keys: UNIQ_848ABB8F2989F1FD
          key: UNIQ_848ABB8F2989F1FD
      key_len: 5
          ref: ontrocrm.i.id
         rows: 1
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: NULL
```

create table is the same in both, one is a backup from the other:

```
CREATE TABLE `invoice` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `number` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `whenCreated` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `unique_number` (`number`),
  KEY `IDX_5FD82ED84DD79520` (`whenCreated`)
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Explaining key_len diff**

You discovered the change that happened with `DATETIME` and `TIMESTAMP` in 5.6.4.  Before, they were 8 bytes (packed decimal) and 4 bytes (just an `INT`), respectively.  Afterwards they are both 5+ bytes, including the ability to include up to 6 decimal places microseconds.

"Using where" does not mean a lot.  "Using index condition" refers to "ICP" or "Index Condition Pushdown", which is an Optimization that *usually* speeds up queries that do not have the an optimal composite index.  [At this point, I need to see `SHOW CREATE TABLE`; I will  *guess* that you are using InnoDB.]  Instead of passing each row from the Engine (InnoDB) back 'up' the 'handler' for further analysis, the 'condition' (`WHERE ...`) is pushed 'down' to the Engine, where it can be more quickly processed.

In *your* case, you get 3x-4x speedup; nice.  (My rule of thumb: 2x.)

**Other**

Are you really doing `SELECT *`?  If you do not need all the columns, should spell out the desired columns; you may be missing some optimization potential.

Is `UNIQ_848ABB8F2989F1FD` "unique", or is it misnamed?

If `invoice.number` is `UNIQUE`, why not use it as the `PRIMARY KEY` and completely get rid of `id`?  This would speed up some operations (though 
probably not the current `SELECT`).

You probably noticed that `OPTIMIZE TABLE` had little or no impact?

Instead of `WHERE i.whenCreated BETWEEN "2017-01-01 00:00:00" AND "2017-01-31 00:00:00"`, which involves an extra second and requires computing the end-of-month, I like to say:

```
WHERE i.whenCreated >= "2017-01-01"
  AND i.whenCreated  < "2017-01-01" + INTERVAL 1 MONTH
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, very useful answer.